# Client sending data very fast and server receiving it slowly without any data loss

Tags: sockets

I am working upon an application based on client and server making use of sockets,in this i am sending data from client to receiver and have made sleep call for 10 sec in server side.Now,when i am sending data from client 1000000 times the server receives it very slowly and the client is printing the values but it is also taking some time in doing so.So, i need to clear following points:

-In both client and server when the values are being displayed there is no loss of data on either side.Does this means that the recv call which is on server side is blocking?

-Secondly,is there any good documentation which could help me to understand better the blocking and non blocking concept of the send and recv calls which are used in sockets programming.

Comment: Sorry, but I just have to ask... what is the 'sleep call for 10 sec' for??

Comment: Is it some kind of test?

Comment: Actually this sleep call is in that thread of server where it is receiving messages which are being sent from client.